# Identification and odd leaf anomaly

Tags: species-identification, botany, trees, toxicology

We're in the process of welcoming sheep, thus setting up the fences, now inside on of the areas, there is a small tree. Never seen leafs like this before. I suspect this to be some sort of anomaly/disease ?.
I identified 2 oddities : the branches are chorros-like and some leafs have small, vivid red appendices growing on them

1. Could anybody identify the tree?
2. are the branches and leafs 'normal'
   3 is there any danger for the sheep? (toxicity) ?

Region : South-west France
Size: About 2 meters

Overall picture : 
[image]

Details :
[image]

[image]

Closeup:
[image]

Comment: Not sure about the tree identification. But regarding the oddity I had to think about [galls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall)

Comment: Could you post it as an answer so I can accept your answer? it's indeed galls on a Ulmus minor.